# My div will not center

Tags: css, html

I am trying to center everything on my page, everything is centered except the div I created. I don't know why. Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
    <div id="mydiv3">
        Get in Contact with the links below!
    </div>
</section>
```

and here is the css:

```
section{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; text-align:center;
}

#mydiv3{
    text-align:center;
    width: 200px;
    border-style:outset;
    border-width: 8px;
}
```

the div I am having problem with is called mydiv3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply `text-align: center` to the `section` element, that will cause all the inline child elements to be centered, which is what you want.  However, since `#mydiv3` is a block element, it won't be affected by the `text-align` property of its parent container.

On the other hand, is you applied `display: inline-block` to `#mydiv3`, then it would align to the center.

The `margin: 0 auto` works as demonstrated because you also assigned a specific width to `#mydiv3`.

Either approach is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to your #mydiv3 rule. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WayDf/)

Answer (score 1):

here is a link that you can use for help. http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/ 
personally i have used

```
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
```

to center a div. apply that to your #mydiv3. Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the `#mydiv3`:

```
margin:auto;
```

See this [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/92D6G/).

Answer (score 0):

To answer why:
`text-align` will align your text to the center, but the `div` is not centered in its parents. Therefore, you need to set the margin as others have suggested.
Of course, one alternative would be to force your `div` to have the same width as your parent and use `text-align`, it would work. This has its own trouble, though; `width: 100%` does not work straight forward.